# default screen background to black iOS

Tags: ios

I see a white launch screen but my application requires black screen by default and all other elements floating.
Im able to covert latter screen black using storyboard but not the default launch screen.

Comment: you need to specify the launch image / screen to display whatever you want

Comment: Care to give us some details? You do know the difference between a *"launch*" screen... which is completely static and has no code behind it... and a *"default"* screen... which is possible to have *"all other elements floating"*. I'm asking because it sounds to me like one or the other - learn about the launch storyboard or add more detail to your question. (Or both?)

Answer (score 0):

create controller for that as  **LaunchScreen.storyboard** can't have any animation only change view background or set an imageView

for that create rootViewController and do the animation in it